# ACOS() Function returns NULL

Tags: mysql

I am little bit confused. Here is my problem

```
mysql> select acos(cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos(radians(-95.712891) - radians(-95.712891)) + sin(radians(37.09024)) * sin(radians(37.09024)));
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| acos(cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos(radians(-95.712891) - radians(-95.712891)) + sin(radians(37.09024)) * sin(radians(37.09024))) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                         NULL |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos(radians(-95.712891) - radians(-95.712891)) + sin(radians(37.09024)) * sin(radians(37.09024));
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos(radians(-95.712891) - radians(-95.712891)) + sin(radians(37.09024)) * sin(radians(37.09024)) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                      1 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know ACOS function has a range [-1,1]. So ACOS (1) must be 0.

```
mysql> select acos(1);                                                                                                       +---------+
| acos(1) |
+---------+
|       0 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

My MySQL version is old, but I can't update.
MySQL Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.22

I made a change

```
select acos(cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos( radians(37.09024) ) * cos(radians(-95.712891) - radians(-95.712891)) + sin(radians(37.09024)) * sin(radians(37.09024))<strong>*1</strong>);
```

And worked. But I didn't get why ACOS (... ****1**) made work. And when I do ACOS (**1***...) Didn't work. If was the case the return not is a number. Both cases should work

Answer (score 0):

[Bug #2338 Trignometric arithmatic problems](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2338) was reported in version 4.0.17, but I can't reproduce the bug in version 5.0.22.

Test:

```sql
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2 to server version: 5.0.22-standard

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 5.0.22-standard | 
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode, @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+-------------------+--------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode | @@SESSION.sql_mode |
+-------------------+--------------------+
|                   |                    | 
+-------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ACOS(COS(RADIANS(37.09024)) * COS(RADIANS(37.09024) ) * COS(RADIANS(-95.712891) - RADIANS(-95.712891)) + SIN(RADIANS(37.09024)) * SIN(RADIANS(37.09024)));
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ACOS(COS(RADIANS(37.09024)) * COS(RADIANS(37.09024) ) * COS(RADIANS(-95.712891) - RADIANS(-95.712891)) + SIN(RADIANS(37.09024)) * SIN(RADIANS(37.09024))) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                                                         0 | 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and the link.. here is the version 5.0.22-log .. And the bug continues..  what is yours gcc version ? here i builded mysql with gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 .. reading the link, seems to be a gcc bug..

Comment: @RicardoGomes: I used the RPM package binaries available in [Linux - Generic (glibc 2.3) (x86, 64-bit), RPM Package MySQL Server](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/file/MySQL-server-5.0.22-0.glibc23.x86_64.rpm) on the CentOS 7 operating system.